# Validate input with a different mode in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form, and the main validation mode is "onChange":

`const formMethods = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' })`

I need to change `mode` prop in specific input (inside a `Controller`), but I don't know how to do.

Code example:

```
<Controller
   control={ control }
   name="fecha"
   defaultValue={ null }
   rules={ {
      required: { ... },
      validate: { ... }
   } }
   render={ ({
      field: { onChange, value, ref },
      fieldState: { error }
   }) => (
      <...></...>
   )}
/>
```

I tried searching props like "mode", but I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no built-in way to do this. An feature request was opened [on GitHub](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/8649) for this exact functionality, but it has since been closed. I've opened [another issue](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/10863) to echo this. Hopefully it gets implemented in the future!

In the meantime, the best solution that I have found is to manually trigger input validation as needed using the [`trigger`](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/trigger) function. The problem with this approach is that it isn't really possible to *prevent* triggering a validation without overriding the event handlers entirely, so in lieu of that, you have to set `mode` to something that fires less frequently than you normally want.

For example, if you wanted to default to validating `onBlur` but want a checkbox to validate `onChange`, you would do something like this:

```
import React from "react"
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form"

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    trigger,
  } = useForm({mode: "onBlur"})
  return (
    <form>
      <input {...register("firstName", {required: true})} />
      <input {...register("lastName", {required: true})} />
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          {...register("agreeToTerms", {
            required: true,
            onChange: () => {
              // Manually trigger a validation for this specific field
              trigger("agreeToTerms")
            },
          })}
        />
        I agree to the terms
      </label>
    </form>
  )
}
```